# Getting image from a input field with Javascript to parse it to an API?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, api, asynchronous

Currently trying to make use of an image upload class I created in php that saves an image to a folder and a text file but I want to save it from an api that I call in Javascript instead of by submitting a form.

Here I am trying to call the api

```
async function createTweet(e) {
  const id = document.getElementById('user-id').getAttribute('data-user-id');

  const tweet = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input')[1]
    .value;
  const image = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input')[0];
  console.log(image);

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('userId', id);
  data.append('tweet', tweet);
  data.append('tweet-image', image);

  try {
    const conn = await fetch('php/api/api-create-tweet.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });

    const res = await conn.text();
    getData();
    // TODO show user he has created a tweet
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Just wondering what I can do with the image so I can read the file in my api with $_FILES['tweet-image'] and if I need to do anything to the form data to make it form type enctype

Comment: Please check my answer (part B) about changing this line: `const image = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input')[0].files[0];` (notice the .files[0]) - did it work?

Answer (score 0):

The code should work with some changes. You have two ways of doing it (see [FormData @ developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)):

Let's say you have a simple form:

```
<!-- just an example -->
<form method="post" action="form.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="tweet" />
    <input type="file" name="image" />    
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
/* prevent sending the form */
var form = document.forms[0];
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendForm();
}
</script>
```

A. importing the `<form>` directly into `FormData()`:

```
<script>
async function sendForm() {
    // import form input here ->
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const conn = await fetch('form.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
    const res = await conn.text();
}
</script>
```

B. make sure you actually append the `.files[0]` from the `input[type="file"]` into the `formData()`:

```
<script>
async function sendForm() {

    const data = new FormData();

    const tweet = form["tweet"].value;
    // notice the use of .files[0] -->
    const image = form["image"].files[0];

    data.append("tweet", tweet);
    data.append("image", image);

    const conn = await fetch('form.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
    const res = await conn.text();
}
</script>
```

Then in your PHP file you should be able to access both `$_POST["tweet"]` (text) and `$_FILES["image"]` (file) in this example.